# InsufficientPermission (403) when trying to link Web Property to AdWords (Google Ads) account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I tried to find a solution for what seems to be a relatively common problem when using the Analytics Management API, unfortunately none answer was helpful.

I'm starting using Analytics Management API with a service account which has a full access to my Analytics account. It was granted Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze and Manage Users permissions at the account level, which means they also are inherited at property level and view level.

I can successfully get the accounts which I have access to, and insert new web properties.

However, I wasn't able to link my Google Ads account to any web property. Anytime I call the API I get a 403 error:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property."}],"code":403,"message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property."}}
```

I checked many times, for each level (account, property and even view) what permissions my service account has, there is always Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze and Manage Users.

Below is how I try to link a Google Ads account:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Management API");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes([
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
]);
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$adWordsAccount = new Google_Service_Analytics_AdWordsAccount();
$adWordsAccount->setCustomerId("XXX-XXX-XXXX");
$adWordsLink = new Google_Service_Analytics_EntityAdWordsLink();
$adWordsLink->setName("TestLink");
$adWordsLink->setAdWordsAccounts([$adWordsAccount]);
try {
  $analytics->management_webPropertyAdWordsLinks->insert(
    999999999, // Analytics Account ID
    "UA-999999999-1", // Tracking ID
    $adWordsLink
  );
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
        . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

} catch (apiException $e) {
  print 'There was a general API error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I know I certainly use more scopes than I need, but using only `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit` gives the same result.

Below is the `service-account-credentials.json` I use (with the key I've generated through Google API Console):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...-230314",
  "private_key_id": "<PRIVATE_KEY_ID>",
  "private_key": "<PRIVATE_KEY>",
  "client_email": "dev-...@ga-....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<CLIENT_ID>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/dev-...%40...-230314.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to link Google Analytics and Google Ads the account performing the link has to be an editor in the Google Analytics Web Property (something apparently you already did) but also needs to be an Admin in the Google Ads Accounts.

Not your personal/corporate Google Account, but in this case the service account itself. The email you included in your `client_email` property in credentials.

Ref: [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en#)

**Caveat:**

I'm not 100% sure you will even be able to do that. Google Ads might require confirmation from the user to b e added into an account, and the fact that you don't have access to the mailbox of the service account may keep you from performing that confirmation. 
Again I'm not sure about this, so I would try, but in case you are not able to add that user to the Google Ads account you'll have to find another method to authenticate the API call using your own email instead of a service account.

Comment: Hi Eduardo,

Thank you for your answer.

I've already tried to add my Service Account as an admin for my AdWords account. But as you said, we can't receive the invite as the Service Account email address isn't accessible.

I'm thinking about using an user account that would be used by my server application through a refresh token (exactly like AdWords API does) but I don't feel this is the right way to do it.

Any thoughts about it?

Comment: I think the right way would be using oAuth. You should be able to approve once and use a refresh key to let it run without manual intervention in the future. [More info](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#installed)